# Disable Interrupts Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, interrupt

I want to disable all the local interrupts on my raspberry pi.
There exist the function: `local_irq_disable();`
But my g++ compiler cannot find it. I tried the common header files like `system.h` and `irq.h`.
But it didn't work.
Which headerfile do I have to use to build the irq_disable function on a raspi with the os raspian ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working on a device driver since this is a function that is meant for code that lives in kernel space, not in user space. The function you are looking for seems to be defined as a preprocessor macro in `linux/irqflags.h`. See [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?a=arm&i=local_irq_disable) for more information.